# Analyze the logic flow of complex hive/spark-sql query and help in optimization

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I would like to know if there are tools that help to visualize the flow of logic in complex hive queries/spark-sql (eg : involving 5 to 6 joins,union etc ) to help me understand more about the query and to do optimizations if necessary .   It would be great if you could share how you generally approach to know the logic flow of a complex query

I tried using "explain", "explain extended" on the query but still it doesn't seem to be helpful for me

[EDIT 1] 
will apache atlas be helpful for the above use-case?

Comment: Don't like the hive (or spark) explain ;)  Completely agree.  Sorry no suggestions on good alternatives however.

Comment: What about Spark UI? isn't it helpful?

Comment: Sorry Spark UI doesn't seem to be helpful..can you share your approach of using Spark UI with a sample query that helps to understand the logic flow of the query ?